# ASP.NET "'Session' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'" master page

Tags: asp.net, session, datalist, objectdatasource

I'm building a website with a shopping cart.
I want all Cart's Item will appear on master page.

This is my SiteMaster.Master.cs:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.Security.MembershipUser user = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();

        IBLClient b = new FrontEnd();
        if (user != null)
            Session["UserID"] = b.GetUserIDByUsername(user.UserName);

        if (Session["Cart"] == null)
        {
            Session["Cart"] = new List<string>();
        }

        if (!(Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") || Roles.IsUserInRole("Seller")))
        {
            ManagePage.Visible = false;

        }

    }


    public BindingList<Product> GetProductsCart()
    {
        IBLClient b = new FrontEnd();
        BindingList<Product> ProductsList = new BindingList<Product>();


        if (Session["Cart"] != null)
        {
            foreach (string ProductId in (List<string>)Session["Cart"])
            {
                ProductsList.Add(b.GetProduct(int.Parse(ProductId)));
            }
        }

        return ProductsList;
    }
```

And this is my Source code:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="ProductsList" runat="server" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="ProductsListObjectDataSource" ForeColor="#333333">
                                    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                </asp:DataList>
                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ProductsListObjectDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetProductsCart" TypeName="WebGUI.SiteMaster"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

When the Page is load it's look like this:

[image]

But after the `ObjectDataSource`'s `SelectMethod` GetProductsCart() function, I got this exeption and the `this` changed.

[image]

Any idea why it's happening?
What should I do to avoid it?

Comment: The issue here is that the moment your function call for the session the session is not available at that call, either is not ready yet, either can not be found from inside that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should do `context.Session` this is the problem!!